# ServiceStack Javascript/Typescript client and CORS

Tags: cors, servicestack

According to the documentation, I believe this is the only line required to enable CORS:

`Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature());`

Then from a different website:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient('https://my-app.azurewebsites.net');
client.get(new something());
```

Error returned is:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
>   value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response
>   is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'.

There is no authentication, I'm using all the defaults, what is missing here in the setup for the JsonServiceClient to make a call to a different server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue ended up being on the JsonServiceClient.  I had to set the credentials to be omitted.

`client.credentials="omit"`

Answer (score 5):

The default for the `CorsFeature` doesn't have allow credentials enabled. Try changing the server to the following.

```
Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(allowCredentials: true));
```

The client will need to include credentials if you are trying to hit an endpoint that requires them to be sent.

EDIT:
Given (I think) you are trying to git an authenticated endpoint from another domain, here is an example of what I use to do the same. Domains have been changed.

```
Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(
    allowCredentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Allow, Authorization, Origin",
    allowOriginWhitelist: new[]
    {
        "https://example.com",
        "https://api.example.com",
        "https://www.example.com",
        "http://dev.example.com"
    }
));
```

Comment: Still doesn't work: `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'https:/my-app2.azurewebsites.net' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: I've updated answer will full example of working auth from another white listed domain.

Comment: I tried that as well.  I figured out the issue, it wasn't the CORS setup so much on the backend but the JsonServiceClient on the front end.  I had to set `client.credentials="omit"`.

Answer (score 2):

I configured the service as mentioned above:

```
Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(
      allowCredentials: true,
      allowedMethods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
      allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Allow, Authorization, Origin",
      allowOriginWhitelist: new[]
             {
                    "http://localhost:4200",
                    "http://localhost:63342",
                    "http://localhost:63342",
                    "http://localhost:3000",
                    "http://my.site.com"
             }));
```

and I have 2 functions Login() and GetContacts()

```
class AppComponent {
***
      constructor(){
        this.client = new JsonServiceClient("http://my.site.com");
        this.client.credentials = "omit";
      }

      async Login(){

        var auth = new wbs.Authenticate();
        auth.UserName = this.username;
        auth.Password = this.password;

        var authResponse = await this.client.post(auth);

        console.log(authResponse);
      }

      async GetContacts(){
        try {
          this.contacts = await this.client.post("Contacts_Get");
          console.log(this.contacts);
        } catch(e) {
          this.contacts = [];
          console.log("Failed to get:", e.responseStatus);
        }
      }
}
```

"servicestack-client": "0.0.30",

I call these functions in turn:

```
1. Login()
2. ContactsGet()
```

The login runs fine, but in Internet explorere and Safari ContactsGet fails, it returns status 401, but works in Chrome.

Help please in what my error?
Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

IIS settings

[image]

Comment: @Layoric please see this post.

Comment: Please upgrade to the latest v0.0.36 of [servicestack-client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-client) which includes Cookies by default.

Comment: @mythz I updated the client to latest version, if I run locally on IIS express works, but when I deploy to IIS server it's not working. Please see update in question.

Comment: Why are you explicitly disabling cookies? `this.client.credentials = "omit";` If you don't know what some configuration please does don't include it, just use the defaults that's embedded in each library.

Comment: Also this should've been a new question but you've added it as an Answer. Answers should answer the specific question that's asked at the top of this page, they shouldn't ask new questions, please open a new question for new questions in future.

Comment: @mythz I tried I tried it and omit without and without. Now create a new question. Thank you.